# JavaFX Line Chart I want to create Curved and linear color below the line

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to make a line chart like this

[image: the graph I want]

I have come close to this by using a line chart.

[image]

anyone please guide me How can I get the result I want.

Comment: See if a chart from [here](https://github.com/GSI-CS-CO/chart-fx) can help.

Answer (score 2):

The area below the line can be colored using the [fill method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Shape.html#fillProperty) if you turn the graph's data line (a Path) into a closed path by including the lines that comprise the side-borders of the chart down to the Y=0 value, and using the ClosePath() method to add the bottom line segment.

Creating a curve to fit a set of points is trickier. Maybe this can be done using `QuadCurve` elements for your path. But the math for fitting a curve on a set of datapoints is over my head. I did spot one tutorial that looked interesting, although it is rather old: [Curve fitting and styling AreaChart](http://fxexperience.com/2012/01/curve-fitting-and-styling-areachart/).